# RoundTo() differences in roundings

Tags: c++, c++builder-6

I am using Borland C++Builder 6.

I have a problem with the `RoundTo()` function.

If I have `RoundTo(number, 0)` where `number = 46.5` then the result is `46`, 
and if I have `RoundTo(number, 0)` where `number = 45.5` then the result is also `46`.

I am searching for a function that every time the decimal is `0.5` the result is rounded up.

Comment: You are maybe using the wrong function, try using 'ceil()' instead.

Comment: Might be that those numbers are not what you think. Being tiny fractions short of the displayed number, that is, your 46.5 being actually 46.5 minus some epsilon. You  might want to try to define some very small number (in the context of the magnitudes of the numbers you deal with) and add it to your numbers before rounding.

Comment: Maybe your 46.5 is not exactly 46.5 but, for example 46.49999999. Rounding that number results is 46.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the result of RoundTo(87.285, -2) => 87.28](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191235/why-is-the-result-of-roundto87-285-2-87-28)

Comment: The standard is to round to the even number, this has a side effect of reducing statistical bias. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Rounding_rules

Answer (score 0):

the ceil function is not good because it rounds numbers to integers and I need to round numbers also after a comma.

My number 46.5 is exactly 46.5 because I tested it by giving it directly to the function and the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not an elegant solution but it works

```
double number, aftercomma;
int intnumber;

number = 46.5;
intnumber = (int)number;
aftercomma = number - intnumber;
if(aftercomma >= 0.5)
   {
    number = Ceil(number);
   }
else
   {
    number = Floor(number);
   }
```